# Usb install, shows cursor only after choosing language in install

Tags: live-usb

After choosing a language, the window that shows the progress of installation disappears leaving only the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting into the live environment and installing from there, if it fails there you most likely have a problem that the computer is unable to mount any drives other than the root usb drive, or the image did not write correctly. Verify you downloaded the image properly and it burned right and then check that the hard drive is connected and that smart data is good. Also, in my experience I've found it is always easier to just burn a dvd and use that as the installation medium, it's cheap and permanent.